# PHP form undefined variable

Tags: php, forms

I am using the PDO but I am confused with the error of undefined variable here:

It concerns the variable cat_name just after the database connection.

I added values directly to the variables. It has changed the error to:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''categories'('cat_name', 'cat_description') VALUES ('ohnoe','ohnoes')' at line 1

```
  <?php
    try{
    include 'database.php';
    $db =  database:: getConnection();
        $catName = "ohnoe";
        $catDesc = "ohnoes";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['cat_name'])){
        $catName = $_POST['cat_name'];
    }
    else{
        echo "already set";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['cat_description'])){
    echo"Oh dear";
    }
    else{
    $catDesc = $_POST['cat_description'];
    }}
    $sqlQuery = ("INSERT INTO 'categories'('cat_name', 'cat_description') VALUES (:cat_name,:cat_description)");

    $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $statement->bindValue(":cat_name",$catName);
    $statement->bindValue(":cat_description",$catDesc);

    $count = $statement->execute();

    $db = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with PDO. It will complain if the variable is not set. You could use `isset()` to check for it first

Comment: Try using `print_r` to see the `$_POST` array, to see if the `cat_name` value actually exists.

Comment: The sql error: your escaping table and column names do not use single quotes, but back ticks

Comment: Just realised it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it is "undefined variable", not an "undefined index"? If you run this script in both case render form and process data, then you have to check the request type by just putting `if ($_POST)` or more specific like `if (isset($_POST['cat_name']) && isset($_POST['cat_description'])` before any data processing.

Comment: I have used the isset function and it has moved over to an undefined index.

Comment: Looks like you ised it wrong. Can you provide a code with using isset?

Comment: Hah, fixed it. Thank you so much!